# C# Обобщенные делегаты c Обобщенными методами

Tags: c#, generics, делегаты

м.б. кто-нибудь поможет!

Задача - передать обобщённый метод в другой класс.

Нерабочий код:

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //Create B
                var bbb = new MyClassB(GetValue);
    
            }
    
    
            //обобщённый метод, который надо передать в класс MyClassB
            public static T GetValue<T>()
            {
                Type type = typeof(T);
                if (type == typeof(int))
                {
                    return (T)(object)5;
                }
    
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
        }

    public delegate T MyDel<T>();


    class MyClassB
    {
        public MyClassB(MyDel<Type> method)
        {
           var n=  method<int>(); //как вызвать метод?
        }


    }
```

Есть какие-нибудь идеи?
Спасибо!

Comment: В C# для передачи "действий" есть уже готовые `Action` - когда надо выполнить, без результата (`void`) и `Func` - когда надо выполнить и получить результат. То есть в вашем случае, я бы сделал так: `MyClassB(MyDel<Type> method)` заменить на `MyClassB(Func<T> method)`, `class MyClassB` -> `class MyClassB <T>`, ну и `new MyClassB(GetValue);` -> `new MyClassB<int>(GetValue<int>);`. Заметьте, в классе B вы сейчас используете `Type` - это не generic! В моем примере я тип задаю самому классу, в виде `T`.

Comment: Спасибо, Ваша идею понял, но мне бы мой вариант сделать...
Если это вообще возможно в C#.
Да, согласен: < в классе B вы сейчас используете Type - это не generic!>,
не знал что туда написать и можно ли вообще так писать...

Comment: `но мне бы мой вариант сделать` - ну так делайте, я вам на ошибки указал, хотите делегат, используйте. `не знал что туда написать` - задавать тип (`T`) в Generic можно либо методам (`void SomeMethod<T>() {}`), либо классам (`class SomeClass <T>{}`), вы же пытаетесь передать тип через конструктор, который не может этого делать. Собственно варианта у вас 2, либо как я показал (с передачей типа классу), либо создать отдельный метод в классе B, который будет принимать метод и тип.

Comment: Вы должны явно указать ``T`` у ``GetValue<T>``, по-другому - никак.

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется делегат `MyDel<T> method`, то его вызов делается так: `method()`.

Чтобы иметь возможность передавать такой делегат в конструктор, нужно задать обобщённый параметр типа на самом классе: `class MyClassB<T>`.

И, наконец, нужно явно указывать тип при создании делегата: `GetValue<int>`.

В итоге, получается примерно следующее:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var b1 = new MyClassB<int>(GetValue<int>); // ok
        var b2 = new MyClassB<string>(GetValue<string>); // exception
    }
                
    public static T GetValue<T>()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(int))
        {
            return (T)(object)5;
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public delegate T MyDel<T>();

class MyClassB<T>
{
    public MyClassB(MyDel<T> method)
    {
        var n = method();
        Console.WriteLine(n + " " + n.GetType());
    }
}
```

---

Возможно, это не то, что вам нужно. Опишите подробнее, что в конечном итоге хотите получить.

Comment: Спасибо! буду пробовать.